# PHP pulling the selected item in an HTML dropdown that is populated from an array to pass in to the database

Tags: php, mysql, html, database

Ok, fist off I apologize for the convoluted and overly long title, but I am very new to all of this and I wasn't quite sure how to explain it or even begin...so I just did!

What I am doing right now is populating an HTML dropdown list from my MySQL database, and then I would like to take whichever option the user selects from the dropdown and somehow enter that data into a different table.

The code I am using to get the data from the table is:

```
<td>Model of Bike</td>
<td><select type ="text" name="bikeBrand">
<?php 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT bikeDescr, bikeID FROM Bikes");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        echo "<option value='bikeDescr'>" . $row['bikeDescr'] . "</option>";
    }
?>
```

Now once the user selects the desired bike, let's say that it is a Trek, I want to be able to get that information and put it into my Insert into () Values () so that I may track which bike they have selected each time a new ticket is created.

Hopefully I have not confused or made the matter worse, but any help as to what I need to do, or where to look would be much appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to do some improvements, they are:

1) The `select` tag doesn't have a `type` attribute, so the correct way to use is:

```
<select name="bikeBrand">
```

2) As you are getting the bikeDescr and bikeID fields in database, i suggest you to use the bikeID as value for each option and bikeDescr to show the option's name. For example:

```
<td>Model of Bike</td>
<td><select name="bikeBrand">

<?php 

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT bikeDescr, bikeID FROM Bikes");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['bikeID'] . "'>" . $row['bikeDescr'] . "</option>";
    }
?>
```

So you can retrieve the bikeBrand value in the next file and insert it in your database.

Comment: You are correct, I need to put the ID into the table and then for my report later I can link the two tables to pull what kind of bike it is. I changed my echo line to what you suggested and it worked like a charm, thank you very much!

Comment: @Huntertusk, I am glad to help you! If you think my answer is the best, please don't forget to mark it.

Comment: thanks for the reminder/infomation. As stated above I don't know what I am doing. I marked it now. Thanks again for everything!

Answer (score 0):

You must change the statement:

```
echo "<option value='bikeDescr'>" . $row['bikeDescr'] . "</option>";
```

to this:

```
echo "<option value='" . htmlentities($row['bikeDescr']) . '>" . $row['bikeDescr'] . "</option>";
```

and this all should be inside a form. As for the `INSERT` query, you are thinking of calling it on the same page or after a button is clicked or a form is submitted?

Comment: I have the insert in a different php file that collects a bunch of information from this form after a button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value you would do
the action on your form as another php file so

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST">
<td><select name="bikeBrand">
<?php 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT bikeDescr, bikeID FROM Bikes");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        echo "<option value='". $row['bikeDescr'] ."'>" . $row['bikeDescr'] . "</option>";
    }
?>
</form>
```

submit.php looks like

```
$value = $_POST['bikeBrand']
if(isset($value)){
// Database info goes here//
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table VALUES('$value')");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of adding another php to do the insert in task, I appreciate it.